# I am sending GET method to server but receiving POST method

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

I am sending GET command to the server but in the Apache log I am  getting POST method.

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.111/shakil/shakil.php/?data=shakil,123,123,123");
JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
postDataParams.put("name", "nazmul");
postDataParams.put("email", "hossainnazmul93@gmail.com");
Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(3000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setConnectTimeout(3000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
```

[image]

Although the method is GET. Can Any one suggest me what is the problem?

Comment: `writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));` is your POST.

Answer (score 2):

Comment this line:

```
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am sending GET method

No you aren't. This line:

```
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

sets the request method to POST. You are also *doing* some output, which doesn't match with a GET request either. If you want a GET, remove the line above and the lines that do the output. Probably you should send the parameters encoded into the URL.